# Nuget Problem After Upgrade .NET version to .NET 6 using .NET Upgrade Assistant

Tags: c#, .net

I am upgrading our .NET 4.7 app to .NET 6 using .NET Upgrade Assistant

Currently I am stuck with an error and several warning.

Here the error (on myApp.csproj file)

> Version conflict detected for System.Security.Permissions. Install/reference System.Security.Permissions 6.0.0 directly to project One to resolve this issue.

The error pointed that I should using nuget System.Security.Permissions 6.0.0
But, each time try to install using menu 'Manage Nuget Package for solution', always failed with error message

> Failed to add reference to 'Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents

I think this warning should be the culprit, but dunno how to fix this

> No way to resolve conflict between "System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Security". Choosing "System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.

Any suggestion Guys?

Edit :
Found out that 'Restore NuGet Packages' is also not working, which the error message pointed to the 'Version conflict detected' above.

So it is now a circular problem..
'Restore NuGet Packages' is failed because the 'Version conflict' which can be fix with install NuGet 'System.Security.Permissions 6.0.0' which cannot be install because 'Restore NuGet Packages' is failed..

Edit 2 : This has been solved.
Some how VS 2022 fix the problem for me automatically.
If you having the same problem, lets discuss our experience

Conclusion : This problem caused by NuGet packages that need to be updated.
We need to trigger the process. In my case by trying to 'Restore NuGet Packages' several times.
If the 'Updates' tab in 'Manage Nuget Package for solution' able to list all package that need to be update, then just run it and this problem will gone.

Comment: Upgrading packages on solution level often fails if you have multiple projects that depend on each other. You can solve it by upgrading libs first or edit the project files directly (= text search in all files for package name, then update version number). Voting to close because we'd need the full project structure to solve this.

Comment: Did you already run something like `Update-Package -Reinstall`? I know I needed that when I upgraded between different 4.* versions, so maybe it's also necessary for upgrading to .Net 6.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen You are correct, but this is a solution with only one project.

I am not agree to close this, because hope that we can get several thought and solution for such problem.

Comment: @grek40 Sound like a potential solution.
I will try to re-run the upgrade process and do your advice.

Comment: Update : The problem has solved now.. 

Previously in 'NuGet Solution' windows I don't see anything on 'Installed' and 'updates' tab. All Nuget packages are gone.

Then some how my NuGet packages shown in 'Installed' tab.
Then after closing and reopen, my NuGet shown in 'updates' tab.

I do the update then the problem solved. 

If anyone encounter the same problem, lets me know so we can discuss.